# Dynamic form with repeating form

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I would like to create a page in android which has to have a **form** which will repeat based on some value **dynamically**.

> Something like this:

[image]

Here form username, password, mobile and address fields are repeated based on number user enters in the the page before this. In this picture the form is repeated twice but it could be any number of times which will be dynamic.

How can I achieve something like this? Can I use `listview` or `recyclerview`? If so then how will I have to retrieve the typed in values?

Comment: About how to use `RecyclerView` in Xamarin.Android, you could refer to : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/recycler-view/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Here form username, password, mobile and address fields are repeated based on number user enters in the the page before this. In this picture the form is repeated twice but it could be any number of times which will be dynamic

**ANS :** you should go with [**`recyclerview`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html)

> How can I achieve something like this?

Create a layout like that  for `recyclerview`  single item

> how will I have to retrieve the typed in values?

You can get values from **`RecyclerView.Adapter`** class

**`HERE IS THE SAMPLE CODE`**

> Activity.java

```
public class AddmoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView myRc;
    ArrayList<AddMorePojo> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Button btnGetData;
    AddMoreAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addmore);

        myRc = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRc);
        btnGetData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetData);

        myRc.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myRc.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        AddMorePojo addMorePojo = new AddMorePojo();
        addMorePojo.setAddress("");
        addMorePojo.setUserName("");
        arrayList.add(addMorePojo);


        adapter = new AddMoreAdapter(this, arrayList);
        myRc.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnGetData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ArrayList<AddMorePojo> pojoArrayList = adapter.getArrayList();

                for (int i = 0; i < pojoArrayList.size(); i++) {

                    Log.e("Name " + i, pojoArrayList.get(i).getUserName() + "");
                    Log.e("Pass " + i, pojoArrayList.get(i).getPass() + "");
                    Log.e("PHONE " + i, pojoArrayList.get(i).getPhone() + "");
                    Log.e("Address " + i, pojoArrayList.get(i).getAddress() + "");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

> Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.user33.workingtestapp.AddmoreActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="get Data" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> pojo class

```
public class AddMorePojo {

    String userName, phone, pass, Address;

    public AddMorePojo() {
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }
}
```

> adapter class

```
public class AddMoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddMoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<AddMorePojo> arrayList;

    public AddMoreAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AddMorePojo> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public AddMoreAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.addmorelayout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AddMoreAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<AddMorePojo> getArrayList()
    {
        return arrayList;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText edtName, edtPhone, edtPass, edtAdrress;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            edtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtUname);
            edtPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
            edtPass = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtPass);
            edtAdrress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtAddress);

            edtName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    AddMorePojo addMorePOJO = arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    addMorePOJO.setUserName(charSequence + "");
                    arrayList.set(getAdapterPosition(), addMorePOJO);


                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });

            edtPhone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    AddMorePojo addMorePOJO = arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    addMorePOJO.setPhone(charSequence + "");
                    arrayList.set(getAdapterPosition(), addMorePOJO);


                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
            edtPass.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    AddMorePojo addMorePOJO = arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    addMorePOJO.setPass(charSequence + "");
                    arrayList.set(getAdapterPosition(), addMorePOJO);


                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });

            edtAdrress.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    AddMorePojo addMorePOJO = arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    addMorePOJO.setAddress(charSequence + "");
                    arrayList.set(getAdapterPosition(), addMorePOJO);


                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

> adapter custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtUname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter User Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="********"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPhone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Address"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I am developing the app in xamarin-android, could you please explain why i will need `textwatcher` and what has been done in `onTextChanged`?

Comment: @Arti the need textwatcher if for that when user change the editext value than it can save in you pojo class

Comment: Where is `getAdapterPosition`?

Comment: @Arti its `RecyclerView `adapter position a public method of `RecyclerView` adapter class check it https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()

Comment: Sorry for asking you silly questions, the syntax and public methods are different in xamarin. android. So I am confused. Could please explain me what does each of this 3 lines do? 
`AddMorePojo addMorePOJO = arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    addMorePOJO.setUserName(charSequence + "");
                    arrayList.set(getAdapterPosition(), addMorePOJO);`

Comment: `addMorePOJO = arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());` this line will get the current object from arraylist in which use input thorugh editext

Comment: `addMorePOJO.setUserName(charSequence + "");` when use chnage value in edittext than this values saved in pojo objcet

Comment: `arrayList.set(getAdapterPosition(), addMorePOJO);` this line will add new input data in arraylist than u can get whenever you want

Comment: @Arti any more doubts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161973/discussion-between-arti-and-nilu).