# designing a dynamic UI for a questionnaire

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create UI for the set of questions coming from back-end like the way it's been done in Ada. I've attached screenshots of desired output below.

What I've done so far is to inflate a linearlayout containing my recyclerview for checkboxes(if the question type is multiple choice) or an edittext on click of a button to render the questions dynamically. But it's only rendering this linearlayout one by one and is not a good strategy in the terms of UX/UI.

Desired output:
[image: question 1]
[image: question 2]

here, on click of the last layout-bound of the previous question, it should navigate by scrolling to that question.

Is there any way I can achieve this other than to do it by inflating a **View** of a `LinearLayout` containing `TextView` and `EditText` or `RecyclerView` *for each question*?

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47975852/7666442

Comment: @Nilu, thank you very much for the info you provided; it looks promising, I'll try to do it and let you know if I need further assistance.

Comment: @welcome let me know if any query

Comment: @Nilu, in your sample code, the single **item** is given height as *wrap-content*. But, in my case I need to **show little part of previous question's item**. I can disable vertical scrolling, but the items will be rendered below each other. What do you suggest about this issue? Should I give some margin to **item** (although, it's bad to do so)?

Comment: may be you try for test case

Comment: @Nilu, Ok, thanks. It's working for now. Though, I need to find some effective solution for margin issue.

Comment: glad it help welcome