# How to prevent recyclerView from resetting edittext when scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mvp

I am trying to create a list with recyclerview (picture below), and inside i have an edittext, textview and those views can be change.

[image]

However the value inside edittext and textview are being resetted if the Recyclerview decide to reinflat it, what i want to know is how does one stop Recyclerview from doing so ? I've googled it for a while, i've tried to Override getItemViewType and still no luck.

Comment: You can use shared preferences.

Comment: simply use a list to store data for each item's edittext and textview. And use that to display it

Comment: check this ans you will get a hint https://stackoverflow.com/a/47975852/7666442

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,

1.Use a list which will have edittext value of items. `//edittextlist`

```
 HashMap<Integer,String> edittextlist=new HashMap<>();
```

If you want to store it permanantly, then use *SharedPref*.

2.Choose item's data which will be unique `//position`

3.Set edittext value based on the edittextlist.

```
if(edittextlist.get(position)!=null) {
        holder.edittext.setText(edittextlist.get(position));
    }
    else {
       holder.edittext.setText("");
    }
```

4. Add listener to your edittext,

```
holder.edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       edittextlist.put(position,s.toString);
       }
});
```