# Keep edit text inside recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have a `recycler view` with 2 view types, 1 is just a `textview` another is just an `edittext`. The `edittext` is always at the bottom of the recycler view below the text. When I am typing in the edittext and scroll up, the `edittext` is recycled but is it possible to keep it from being recycled and allow users to keep typing after scrolling up?

Comment: Please share your layout code for better understanding of your requirement and to see what you implemented so far.

Comment: check this answer  **[recyclerView with edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47975852/7666442)**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to disable view recycling (and you understand the tradeoffs), you are better off using a LinearLayout and adding views at runtime to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to user recycler view and also want to retain entered text, you have to use TextWatcher(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) and need to save changed text in your collection object.

```
editTextInstance.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
             collcectionInstance.get(position).setName(s);
   }
  });
```