# Update RecyclerView List after adding a row and also set user entered values from that row to the recyclerview list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a recyclerview that contains cardViews with edittext, datepicker & spinner. Each cardview has (+) button which can be used to add a new cardview to the recyclerview. The problem that i am facing is that **i want to get values from all the cards available in recyclerview including the newly added card into an object type arraylist**. For the time being i am able to add a new blank card but not able to catch user entered values from that card into list.

[image]

***I want to save the above pink marked values into the recyclerview list so that i can save it to server using rest api.***

**EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.java**

```
package abc.com.abcpos.forms;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import abc.com.abcpos.Adapters.EducationInfoAdapter;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.SavingUrls;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.Validations;
import abc.com.abcpos.Handlers.HttpHandler;
import abc.com.abcpos.MainActivity;
import abc.com.abcpos.Models.EmpEducationDetailsModel;
import abc.com.abcpos.Models.EmpPersonalDetails;
import abc.com.abcpos.R;
import abc.com.abcpos.WelcomeActivity;

public class EmpEducationInfoFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    boolean connected=false;
    String jsonStr;
    NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod numKeyBoard;
    EmpEducationDetailsModel empEducationDetailsModelObject;
    private ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> empEducationDetailsModelLists;
    private ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> saveEducationDetailsModelLists;
    private RecyclerView empEducationDetailsRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter empEducationDetailsAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager empEducationDetailsLayoutManager;
    Button saveBtn,cancelBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emp_education_info_form);
        initViews();
        initListeners();

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
            connected=true;
        }else{
            connected=false;
        }

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private void initViews(){
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarEmpEducationInfoFormActivity);
        toolbar.setTitle("Education Details");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolBarTitle));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        saveBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        cancelBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

        numKeyBoard=new NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod();

        empEducationDetailsModelLists=new ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails>();

        empEducationDetailsRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_EducationDetailsActivity);
        empEducationDetailsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    private void initListeners(){

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jo1=new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray ja1=new JSONArray();
                    for(int j=0;j<saveEducationDetailsModelLists.size();j++){
                        try {
                            jo1.put("userId",empEducationDetailsModelLists.get(j).getUserId());
                            jo1.put("education",saveEducationDetailsModelLists.get(j).getEducation());
                            jo1.put("university",saveEducationDetailsModelLists.get(j).getUniversity());
                            jo1.put("marks",saveEducationDetailsModelLists.get(j).getMarks());
                            jo1.put("passingYear",saveEducationDetailsModelLists.get(j).getPassingYear());
                            jo1.put("stream",saveEducationDetailsModelLists.get(j).getStream());
                            jo1.put("grade",saveEducationDetailsModelLists.get(j).getGrade());

                            ja1.put(j,jo1);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    Sender s = new Sender(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this, SavingUrls.sending_personal_det_url,ja1);
                    s.execute();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //checkValidation();
                /*Intent i = new Intent(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("submitFlags", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("educationInfoFlag", true);
                prefsEditor.commit();
                startActivity(i);*/
            }
        });
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;

        }
    }

    public void sendAllDataToServer(ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> mEmpEducationDetailsList) {
        saveEducationDetailsModelLists=mEmpEducationDetailsList;
    }


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails>> {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            try{
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
                String url = "http://202.38.173.190:8080/TelephoneDirectoryApi/getAllCategoryData";
                Date date = new Date();

                if (connected) {
                    /*jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);*/
                    jsonStr="[{\"userId\":\"kbg-000002\",\"education\":\"Graduation\",\"university\":\"sdsa\",\"marks\":\"321\",\"passingYear\":\"3232\"," +
                            "\"stream\":\"dsdsa\",\"grade\":\"d\",\"empEducationList\":null},{\"userId\":\"kbg-000002\",\"education\":\"Post Graduation\"," +
                            "\"university\":\"sdsa\",\"marks\":\"321\",\"passingYear\":\"3232\",\"stream\":\"dsdsa\",\"grade\":\"d\",\"empEducationList\":null}]";

                    if (jsonStr != null) {
                        try {
                            ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> empEducationList = new ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails>();
                            JSONArray eduArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                            for (int i = 0; i < eduArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = eduArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String userId = jsonobject.getString("userId");
                                String education = jsonobject.getString("education");
                                String university = jsonobject.getString("university");
                                String marks = jsonobject.getString("marks");
                                String passingYear = jsonobject.getString("passingYear");
                                String stream = jsonobject.getString("stream");
                                String grade = jsonobject.getString("grade");

                                empEducationList.add(new EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails(userId,education,university,marks,passingYear,stream,grade));
                            }
                            empEducationDetailsModelLists.addAll(empEducationList);

                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this,
                            "Sorry! You are not connected to internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return empEducationDetailsModelLists;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> empEducationDetails) {
            super.onPostExecute(empEducationDetails);
            if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            empEducationDetailsAdapter=new EducationInfoAdapter(empEducationDetailsModelLists,EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this);
            empEducationDetailsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            empEducationDetailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(empEducationDetailsAdapter);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private class Sender extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        Context c;
        String urlAddress;
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this);
        JSONArray jsonArray;

        public Sender(Context c, String urlAddress, JSONArray jsonArray) {
            this.c = c;
            this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
            this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pd.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return this.send();
        }

        private String send() {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(SavingUrls.sending_edu_det_url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                String input = jsonArray.toString() ;

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                os.write(input.getBytes());
                os.flush();

                if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                            + conn.getResponseCode());
                }

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (conn.getInputStream())));

                String output;
                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }

                conn.disconnect();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            pd.dismiss();

            if (s != null) {
                Toast.makeText(c, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Unsuccessful " + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EducationInfoAdapter.java**

```
package abc.com.abcpos.Adapters;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.Validations;
import abc.com.abcpos.Models.EmpEducationDetailsModel;
import abc.com.abcpos.R;
import abc.com.abcpos.forms.EmpEducationInfoFormActivity;

public class EducationInfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EducationInfoAdapter.EducationViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> mEmpEducationDetailsList;
    Context ctx;

    Validations validationsObj =new Validations();

    public EducationInfoAdapter(ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> mEmpEducationDetailsList,Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.mEmpEducationDetailsList = mEmpEducationDetailsList;
        }

    public void addItem(){
        mEmpEducationDetailsList.add(new EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails());
        notifyItemInserted(mEmpEducationDetailsList.size() - 1);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EducationInfoAdapter.EducationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_educationinfo, parent, false);
        return new EducationViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final EducationInfoAdapter.EducationViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        try{
            holder.nameOfBoardEditText.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getUniversity());
            holder.marksObtained.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getMarks());
            holder.stream.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getStream());
            holder.grade.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getGrade());
            holder.passingYear.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getPassingYear());
            if (mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getEducation().toString() != null) {
                int spinnerPosition = holder.adapter.getPosition(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getEducation().toString());
                holder.educationSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
            }

            if(ctx instanceof EmpEducationInfoFormActivity){
                ((EmpEducationInfoFormActivity)ctx).sendAllDataToServer(this.mEmpEducationDetailsList);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEmpEducationDetailsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public List<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> retrieveEduData()
    {
        return mEmpEducationDetailsList;
    }

    public class EducationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText passingYear,marksObtained,stream,grade,nameOfBoardEditText;
        Spinner educationSpinner;
        String[]paths = {"Select Education", "Matriculation", "Higher Secondary", "Graduation","Post Graduation","Technical","Professional"};
        NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod numKeyBoard;

        TextInputLayout educationDetailsTextInputLayout,educationDetailsTextInputLayout1,educationDetailsTextInputLayout2,
                educationDetailsTextInputLayout3,educationDetailsTextInputLayout4,educationDetailsTextInputLayout5;

        Button addEmpEducation,delEmpEducation;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        public EducationViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            passingYear=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.passingYear);
            marksObtained=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.marksObtained);
            stream=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stream);
            grade=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grade);
            nameOfBoardEditText=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfBoardEditText);

            marksObtained.setTransformationMethod(numKeyBoard);

            educationDetailsTextInputLayout=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout1=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout1);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout2=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout2);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout3=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout3);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout4=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout4);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout5=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout5);

            educationSpinner=(Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationSpinner);

            addEmpEducation=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addEmpEducation);
            delEmpEducation=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delEmpEducation);

            passingYear.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    validationsObj.dateDialog(passingYear,(Activity) v.getContext(),event);
                    //mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setPassingYear(String.valueOf(passingYear.getText()));
                    return true;
                }
            });
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(itemView.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            educationSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            delEmpEducation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), mEmpEducationDetailsList.size());
                }
            });
            addEmpEducation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    /*mEmpEducationDetailsList.add(new EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails());
                    notifyItemInserted(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), mEmpEducationDetailsList.size());*/
                    addItem();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975286/dynamic-form-with-repeating-form and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51454770/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod : Could you please look into my code and guide me what changes do i need as i am a novice in this field?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem, first you have to use **interface** for both deletion and addition of card, using interface you have to update **Arraylist** of **EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.java** class, after that you have to call **empEducationDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**;

For **deletion** of card, **remove the record from arraylist of particular postion** and after that call **empEducationDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**; it will refresh the recyclerview.

For **addition** of card, **add new data in arraylist at last postion** and after that call **empEducationDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**; it will refresh the recyclerview.