# Without any event like click how to get values from edit text

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recylerview with edit text on its row which is populated with values coming from the server.

Now the user will be able to add some edit text and some not. My problem is that if user entered some values in edit text then I am able to get these values and other not. Lets say recylerview has 5 edit text and user entered values in 2 edit text then I have to receive these 5 edit text values into containing activity of adapter.is that possible or edit text is recommended on rv?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454613/how-can-i-validate-recyclerview-adapter-textinputedittext-from-fragment/51454770#51454770 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975286/dynamic-form-with-repeating-form

Comment: Do findElementById and then use element.getText();

Comment: i did it. i think u did not get my point @Kaushal28

Answer (score 0):

You can add a text change listener to the edit texts

refer: [android on Text Change Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)

Comment: its not works for because i have to add these values into list on each key list size got increased and if user not change the text then  i am not able to add these values into list