# How to add limited edit text on button click and get all edit text data in array?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have one button add more. when user click button one edit text added and user can click only  10 times.All Edit text show in vertically.  How can i do this? I have no idea. Also I get all edit text data in one array. How can I do this?

Comment: While you are clicking on button you need to add in to arrayList and fill the adapter. When list size will reach to `>=10` then disable click event of button.

Comment: can you give me any example of this?

Comment: related [Dynamic form with repeating form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975286/dynamic-form-with-repeating-form)

Comment: @DarshiDomadiya Do you have only simply edittext view or any other views?

Comment: I have only simple edit text view  no  other views

Comment: Then you need to take one String arraylist and add value of edittext in array list and fill your adapter. You can also use model (pojo) class and make list of it.

Comment: ok but how can i add edit text when button clicked

Comment: see this https://nelsoncvjr.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/addremove-layout-dynamically-on-android/