# Update recyclerview inside afterTextChanged() event of TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclervew` which has `textwatcher` in every item. I am looking to update the `recyclerview` after user finishes entering value in `edittext`. Tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `afterTextChanged()` method. But that doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975286/dynamic-form-with-repeating-form and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454613/how-can-i-validate-recyclerview-adapter-textinputedittext-from-fragment/51454770#51454770

Answer (score 0):

Just re initialize adapter

```
newItemsData = getItems()// If you want to changes list data
mAdapter = new RecylerViewAdapter(newItemsData);
```

or if you list is already changed
   just call

```
mAdapter.notifydatasetChanged()
```

Comment: not a very good ideea to create a new instance of your adapter, though

Comment: Since in above question there is no code thought of suggesting possibilities for updating recylerview